# Add background image to RelativeLayout in android

Tags: android, android-layout, background, background-image

I tried to add a background image to an Android app using `android:background="@drawable/imageURL"`. I added the image to the `drawable-hdpi` folder, but I'm getting an error. I'm trying to add the image to a `RelativeLayout`. I also tried to use `LinearLayout` but it didn't work either.

So how to add background image to my app within `RelativeLayout` in Android?

What is the error?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/abc.png"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What is the error?  ._.

Comment: Try `android:background="@drawable/abc"` (without file extension)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

replace

```
android:background="@drawable/abc.png"
```

with

```
android:background="@drawable/abc"
```

From the documentation:

> May be a reference to another resource, in the form
>   "@[+][package:]type:name"

as you can see the extension is not part of the value of the attribute

Answer (score 1):

just write `@drawable/abc` instead of `@drawable/abc.png`